# How to condense environments and options to one environment?

Tags: macros, environments, optional-arguments, environment-variables

In order to make grey boxes around code in my document I am using:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage{mdframed} %nice frames
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=light-gray, roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15, outerlinewidth=1, linecolor=light-gray]  
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
    Program here
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
```

Is there any way to condense the two begin's with junk into one begin{program} end{program}? I am pretty new to Late and am not sure how to make these custom commands.

Comment: Have you had a look at the tcolorbox package. If I'm not mistaken, it provides a combined construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\surroundwithmdframed[<options>]{<environment>}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %nice frames
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack

\surroundwithmdframed[backgroundcolor=light-gray, roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15, outerlinewidth=1, linecolor=light-gray]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python,caption={A test listing}]
    Program here
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

By the way, you should use

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %nice frames
```

as I did in my example; otherwise, some options (such as `roundcorner`) will be ignored.

However, I'd like to suggest you an alternative using the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and its nice interaction with `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} %custom colours
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %nice frames
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95} %the shade of grey that stack

\newtcblisting{mytcbox}[1][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=light-gray,
  colframe=light-gray,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=10pt,
  auto outer arc,
  listing only,
  listing options={#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytcbox}[language=Python]
    Program here
\end{mytcbox}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks great. However, for some reason captions aren't showing up now.

Comment: @user2154420 Please see my updated answer. Captions work OK. Are you getting something different? If so, please consider opening a follow-up question.